# Can TLS participants change ip ?

Tags: ssl, networking, tcp

What will happen if one of TLS participants will change it IP? For example it is HTTPS session and client changes it network form LAN to WiFi with other white IP address (given from the NAT). Will TLS session break? Or the server will accept data from new TCP connection because all messages have valid HMAC for this session?

Comment: The TCP connection will break.

Comment: `Or the server will accept data from new TCP connection` so I understand this